# Connection Problem of Xmeta Database on Datastage

Tags: etl, datastage

I have a problem about connection of the db2 connector to metadata repository database (XMETA- inside datastage- not remote). I can connect to XMETA database on terminal with db2inst1 user. But I can not connect with DB2 Connector Stage with the db2inst1 user.

I gave this error;

"SQL1013N  The database alias name or database name "XMETA" could not be found. 
SQLSTATE=42705"

Is there any suggestion about this situation?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to catalog the database as a remote one even though it is on the local system.
For Db2 this could be done by running a `catalog tcpip node` command and a `catalog database`. You might have to use a different DB Alias to differentiate the two entries in the system database directory.

Comment: But I can connect to database with the same user on terminal. If it is not be catalog, how can I connect to this database same user on terminal?

Comment: Have you tried it? For a local connection Db2 is not waiting for a password and therefore you as db2inst1 are able to connect through the command line. Give it a try  it might solve your problem

Comment: Thank you Michael. I will try to catalog.